# How to build PCL for OpenNI2?

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, openni

I have a Astra Pro 3D sensor from Orbecc and it uses OpenNI for grabbing.

But PCL which is precompiled form http://pointclouds.org/ uses OpenNI not the OpenNI2. So when I try to run any sample program, I get "No devices connected" error.

After some research I found that I need to build PCL for OpenNI2. As I am very new to PCL I don't know how to do that.

Can anyone please help me to build PCL with OpenNI2.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on my Linux System. 
I solved this problem, by compiling PCL myself. The Tutorial from [this](http://robotica.unileon.es/index.php/PCL/OpenNI_tutorial_0:_The_very_basics) source was quite helpful for me. But take care: this is intended to build with OpenNI.

For using OpenNI2 I had to take care, that it is already installed on the my system (I did this also by building the sources). When executing cmake, using `cmake ..` in a build directory inside the downloaded OpenNI2 source, it should appear as found.

In this build directory you will find following file: `bin/pcl_openni2_viewer`. This can be used to test PCL with OpenNI2.

If you have the issue, that no device can be found and you get an output similar to this

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pcl::IOException'
  what():  void pcl::io::OpenNI2Grabber::setupDevice(const string&, const pcl::io::OpenNI2Grabber::Mode&, const pcl::io::OpenNI2Grabber::Mode&) in /home/dev/pcl/io/src/openni2_grabber.cpp @ 325 : No devices connected.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

OpenNI2 can not detect your camera properly and some camera specific files are missing.

I use an [LIPS](http://www.lips-hci.com/) ToF camera and got some sources to compile for my system. For for testing OpenNI2 I had to take care that some of these files are copied next to the executeables. For using them with the PCL I copied them to `/usr/local/lib` and everything worked fine for me.

Hope that helps! - Cheers